# Tool to diff webpage semantic structure rather than content

Tags: diff, compare, semantics

Does anyone know of any tools that allow diff'ing between two web pages semantic markup rather than content?

Cheers.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Most diff tools diff the code, which would be the markup and content rather than diffing either one of those.  Are you asking if you could diff the code with the content removed?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you might have more success if you break it down into two steps:

1. Remove content
2. Diff

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Pretty Diff tool.  It would require a minor customization to the markup beautification component so that content components are set to empty strings.

Look at http://prettydiff.com/markup_beauty.js

Change lines 554, 557, and 560 to:
build.push("know text");

These change would actually need to occur in the larger prettydiff.com/prettydiff.js, but now you know where to look.  Once done you can run all this off your local.

All you will need is:

- HTML of http://prettydiff.com/
- prettydiff.com/diffview.css
- prettydiff.com/pd.js - this is the DOM interface between the application and the HTML
- prettydiff.com/prettydiff.js - this is the actual application code.

I may write this concept of ignoring content into the tool as an option.